# Show that it is a positive summation kernel

Tags: summation, fourier-analysis

Let
$$
K(x) = \frac{3}{4}(1-x^2)
$$
for $|x|<1$ and $0$ elsewhere

Show that

$$
K_n(x):=nK(nx)
$$
is a positive summation kernel.

Solution:
So I want to show that

$$
K_n(x)≥0 \\
\int_{-1}^{1}K_n(x)dx =1 \\
if \,\delta>0 \, then \,, \,\lim_{n->\infty}\int_{\delta<|x|<1}K_n(x)dx = 0
$$

I'm stuck on the second criteria, tried to just plug it in but I get an expression in terms of n, is that right? Can anyone show this part for me?

$$
\int_{-1}^1n\frac{3}{4}(1-n^2x^2)dx = n\frac{3}{4}\int_{-1}^1(1-n^2x^2)dx = n\frac{3}{4} \left[ x-\frac{n^2}{3}x^3 \right] _{-1}^1 = n\frac{6-2n^2}{4}
$$
clearly this goes bananas for large $n$

Comment: Could you write out what you get?

Comment: I've added that to the question.